# I can't install Steam properly!

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-installation, steam, 32-bit

Here's my specs and stuff: https://pastebin.com/w3SCkLAN.
I have tried multiple ways to download Steam. First is using the .deb, it required the 32-bit libraries I can't, and don't know how to, install. Second is using the terminal. I downloaded Steam and the Steam update, but after that, it doesn't open. Uninstalled it. What should I do?

Now, it says "Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so".

Extra info:

```
icebunny08@D3CRYPT3D:~$ sudo apt install steam
[sudo] password for icebunny08: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
steam:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 267 not upgraded.
icebunny08@D3CRYPT3D:~$ steam
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/icebunny08/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
icebunny08@D3CRYPT3D:~$
```

Comment: I am currently on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: I installed `steam-installer` and `steam-launcher`. It still requires the 32-bit libraries

Comment: Now, it says "Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so".

Comment: I think I have worked out a solution for you... plz see answer.

Comment: Joshua, I have already tried your solution. After updating Steam, it doesn't open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to enable the i386 arch:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

Now make sure your old repo is disabled by running:

```
$ sudo software-properties-gtk
```

and look to see if there is a Steam repo in "other software" tab. If so delete it before proceeding.

You can be sure all requirements are installed using:

```
$ sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Then you can try to reinstall steam:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt remove --purge steam-launcher steam-installer steam-devices steam && sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install steam steam-devices
```

Finally, if running steam from command line does not work, try launching it from activities window.

More info available [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

Comment: Doesn't work. https://pastebin.com/fSz05Dbk

Comment: Looks like those * I was trying to use didn't work... updating answer now...\

Comment: I think you need to make sure to delete the old repo before purging.. I have polished my answer... let me know if it works now.

Comment: I have done this before. I cancelled it for the mean time because when I did this before, after updating, Steam doesn't open. I have a backup of ./steam and /.local/share/steam or whatever the file path is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but I can't comment yet so...

You need to remove the Steam Repo that was installed with the .deb package, then update apt and remove the old installation. I don't know the command for removing a repository but you can use `software-properties-gtk` and remove it from the "Other Software" tab.

`http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease`

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge steam*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Also, make sure the `.steam` directory is gone. If its not gone then delete it.

I think the `steam-launcher` package came from the old repo, on my system the only Steam packages are:

```
steam:i386
steam-devices
steam-installer
```

The `steam:i386` package is what is installed by `sudo apt install steam`.
I'm not sure, but from the apt descriptions it seems that `steam-devices` is for using Valve's Steam hardware, and `steam-installer` is for people trying to install Steam with i386 emulation on other architectures (such as PowerPC).

After you've removed the old repository and installation just do:

`sudo apt install steam` **NO ASTERISK (*)**

If it won't install, consider that the graphics PPA you are using might be causing a conflict.

Comment: I can confirm that `steam-devices` is what make your controller work.

Answer (score 0):

Download Steam from [their download page](https://store.steampowered.com/about/) and to install the downloaded deb package, run

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

Comment: This should not work for most users. Steam requires many dependencies, which dpkg won't handle.